# Get an image src from a webview in android

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am trying to get the src of a captcha image found in a webview but when i type the below code the output says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null
```

and another question if i get the image src how can i put the image in an image view?

any help will be really appreciated

here is my code so far:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv) ;
mImgCaptcha = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCaptcha);
        done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);
        contentView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        code = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.code);





        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("https://noor.moe.gov.sa/NOOR/Login.aspx");




            wv.loadUrl("javascript:var a = document.getElementById('imgCaptcha').src;");
            System.out.println(wv.getUrl());







        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                        wv.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementById('tbPublic').value = '" + username.getText().toString() + "';");
                        wv.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementById('tbPrivate').value = '" + password.getText().toString() + "';");
                        wv.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementById('tbCaptcha').value = '" + code.getText().toString() + "';");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    wv.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
                            "l=document.getElementById('btnLogin');" +
                            "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');" +
                            "e.initEvent('click',true,true);" +
                            " l.dispatchEvent(e);" +
                            "})()");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the page is not loaded yet when you are trying to query the DOM. You need to query the DOM when you can be sure that the page has loaded.

We need to set the `WebViewClient` for the webview and then listen to `onPageFinished` event. The code might look something like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        // you can now query the DOM.
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:var a = document.getElementById('imgCaptcha').src;");
    }
});
```

Further reading: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%2520java.lang.String)

Comment: thanks now the output doesn't show the error anymore but after getting the image src how can i show it, like the src is www.html.com/image how can i show that text in a textview for example?